# What is the function of this code snippet?

Tags: c++, opencv, grayscale

Could someone explain the code below?

```
grey.create(sizes[0],sizes[1],CV_8U);
```

Comment: read the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html#matthebasicimagecontainer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`create()`**](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html) is a member function of `cv::Mat` class.

```
void Mat::create(int rows, int cols, int type)
```

It is used to create a `cv::Mat` and allocates new array data if needed.

In your example, `grey` will be a `sizes[0] x sizes[1]` matrix, i.e. `Mat` image with type `CV_8U`. `grey` can be viewed as a gray-scale image here with only one-channel, which is equivalent to:

```
Mat grey(sizes[0], sizes[1], CV_8UC1);
```